# A generalisation of Cauchy-Stieltjes transform

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, integral-transforms

For a nice function $\nu$ (say smooth and compactly supported), its Cauchy-Stieltjes transform is defined as
$$\int_\mathbb R \frac{\nu(s)}{z-s}\mathrm{d}s$$
which is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb R$. It has also an inverse transform which can recover $\nu$.

If we replace the $s$ in the denominator by $\partial_s$, we can define a different transform
$$f(s)\mapsto \int_\mathbb R f(s) \frac{1}{z-\partial_s}w(s)\mathrm{d}s:=\int_\mathbb R f(s) \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\partial_s^k w(s)}{z^{k+1}}\mathrm{d}s$$
with a given weight function $w$. It is a curious question to see its analyticity and inverse transform, etc.

My question is, is this something known from the literature? Or, is there anything similar to this which has been studied before?

Comment: $\partial_s^k e^s =e^s$, so the second equality seems wrong, even as a purely formal manipulation. (There is also the issue of whether these formal operations can be justified.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes you are right. There is still some connections between this and the ordinary Cauchy transform while it would need some other heavy theories to see it. I haven't found a simple way to relate them.